Nonlinear recurrence relationship for motion down a bumpy ramp
I'm having some fun with recurrence relations that are showing up for a project I'm working independently on and I'm wondering if anyone has done something with a similar one.
The recurrence relation is
$$x_n^2=W+(x_{n-1}-u)^2$$ where $W$ and $u$ are both positive constants, and $x_0=0$. I know it has a stable fixed point $$x=\frac{W+u^2}{2u}$$ so I tried a trial function $x_n=\frac{W+u^2}{2u}f(n)$ and was able to show that $$\frac{f^2(n+1)-f^2(n)}{1-f(n)}=constant$$
That's as far as I've been able to go beyond finding specific numerical solutions! I know there is no guarantee a nonlinear recurrence is going to have a closed form solution but wanted to see if anyone had ideas. Thanks!

Is $L=u$ in $x_n$?

Yes, sorry I've been going back and forth between the two in my own notes- will edit now.
